# Is it possible to redeliver a Celery worker's tasks as soon as the worker stops sending heartbeat?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat, celeryd

According to the celery [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout) on Celery using Redis broker,

> The visibility timeout defines the number of seconds to wait for the worker to acknowledge the task before the message is redelivered to another worker

This means that if a worker crashes during execution of a task, the same task will be delivered to another worker after this timeout. However, I also noticed that Celery workers sent heartbeats to each other(probably via the broker). Is it possible to leverage these heartbeats to redeliver task to healthy workers as soon as an unhealthy worker stops sending heartbeats? The advantage of this is that tasks handled by a failed worker can be picked up much sooner than if we had to wait for the visibility timeout(which defaults to 1 hour).

Answer (score 1):

That would require some complex logic to be set in place... I would rather rely on [task_reject_on_worker_lost](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_reject_on_worker_lost) instead.

Comment: I tested doing this on RabbitMQ and it works as expected. It doesn't seem to work with Redis as message broker though. Do you have any suggestions about how to solve that problem?